# How to notate the restriction of an inverse of a function?

Tags: functions, notation

Let $f$ be a function, which is defined on $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, and which is mapping to an extended real numbers. That is,
$$f:E\longrightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$$

Then, for a subset $A$ of $E$ $\left(\text{i.e.}~A\subset{}E\right)$,
$$f~\big|_A:A\longrightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$$

---

For an open set $G$, let $f^{-1}(G)=G^*$.

If I want to restrict $f^{-1}$ to a set $H$, how can I write it?

Which one is correct?
$$f~\big|_H^{-1} = G^* \cap H$$

$$f^{-1}\big|_H = G^* \cap H$$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $f^{-1}(G) = G^{*}$—without specifying that $f$ is invertible—implicitly defines a mapping $f^{-1}$ from the *power set* of the extended reals to the power set of $E$, not a mapping from the extended reals to $E$. Consequently, "restriction of $f^{-1}$ to $H$" doesn't make sense (unless you intend to restrict to $H$ viewed as an element of a power set, which seems unlikely).

In any case, neither proposed formula is grammatically correct; each has a mapping on the left and a set on the right.

Be that as it may,

- $f^{-1}\big|_{H}$ denotes the restriction of the inverse of $f$ to $H$;
- $f\big|_{H}{}^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of the restriction of $f$ to $H$.

I'm guessing you're really asking: "If $H$ is a subset of the extended reals, what is the proper notation for $f^{-1}(H)$?"

If that's right, reasonable answers include $H^{*}$ (if you want the inverse image of $H$ itself) or $G^{*} \cap H^{*} = (G \cap H)^{*}$ (if you want the inverse image of the intersection $G \cap H$, which is not unlike a "restriction of $f^{-1}(G)$ to $H$").

Comment: I'm sorry because of my poor English. I edited my post, adding the picture. I drew the picture by mspaint program with mouse. Thus, it's bad quality... sorry T.T

Comment: To clarify, then: Are you trying to express $f\big|_{G^{*} \cap H}$, the restriction of $f$ to $G^{*} \cap H$? Or do you want to express $f^{-1}(f(G^{*} \cap H))$, the inverse image of the image of $G^{*} \cap H$? Or something else? :)

Comment: To ask in another way, why is "$G^{*} \cap H$" not the answer to your question? (Separately, your English is great; I wouldn't have suspected you're not a native speaker.)

Comment: Ah, I want to express that $f^{-1}\left(f\left(G^*\cap{}H\right)\right)$. And $G^*\cap{}H$ can't be the answer because $G^*$ and $H$ are not given to me.

Comment: Actually, I want to express the restriction of $f^{-1}\left(\left(c, +\infty\right)\right)$ to $[a, b]$, where $f$ is defined on $(-\infty, +\infty)$. However, I don't know which are correct between $f\big|_{[a, b]}^{-1}((c,+\infty))$ and $f^{-1}\big|_{[a, b]}((c,+\infty))$, or both are incorrect.

Comment: If I understand, you want$$[a, b] \cap f^{-1}((c, \infty)) = f\big|_{[a, b]}{}^{-1}((c, \infty)),$$the inverse image of $(c, \infty)$ under the restriction of $f$ to $[a, b]$. If that's right, I'll edit this answer (later today, probably not for several hours).

Comment: I got it. Thank you. That is what I want to know.